# Tuples or Keyword Lists in Elixir functions

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

On page 221 of the [Programming Elixir](https://pragprog.com/book/elixir/programming-elixir) book, it's stated that if we want to pass multiple values in a `call` to a `GenServer`, we should use tuples:

```
def handle_call({:set_number, new_number}, _from, _current_number) do
{ :reply, new_number, new_number }
end

iex> GenServer.call(pid, {:set_number, 999})
```

It seems to me that Keyword Lists would be a much better fit in this case:

```
def handle_call([ set_number: new_number ], _from, _current_number) do
  { :reply, new_number, new_number + 1 }
end

iex(2)> GenServer.call pid, set_number: 999
```

This way I can avoid braces altogether, and I'm using keyword lists for what seems to be their purpose: passing options/arguments around.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Or am I contravening some best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keyword Lists](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/maps-and-dicts.html#keyword-lists) are lists of 2-item tuples. So `[set_number: 999]` is equivalent to `[{:set_number, 999}]`.

Tuples are usually used in those cases since they are more versatile than keyword lists. Keyword lists are confined to 2 item tuples, when in some cases you want to pass a 3-item tuple (or more). Consider the case of a key-value storing `GenServer`. To store a value, you need to pass a 3-item tuple in the form of `{:put, key, value}`.

"Avoiding braces altogether" should not be the deciding factor of the data type used. Also note, that the client should not be aware of the server implementation and as such, you usually define a client API.

```
defmodule MyModule do
  use GenServer

  #client API
  def set_number(pid, number) do
    GenServer.call(pid, {:set_number, number})
  end

  def handle_call({:set_number, new_number}, _from, _current_number) do
    { :reply, new_number, new_number }
  end
end
```

Now from the `iex`, you can just call:

```
iex > MyModule.set_number(pid, 999)
```

This way, if you need to change server implementation, nothing on the client side needs to change.

Comment: Yep, you're right in that I'm exposing the raw innards, but as I mentioned, I'm going through a book, and that refactoring came after I wrote this question :)